# Osmdroid POI info window crashes app

Tags: android, osmdroid, nominatim

I'm getting 2 errors when trying to click on a marker for POI.

```
BasicInfoWindow: unable to get res ids in com.JEB.trailmaps
```

And

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.infowindow.BasicInfoWindow.onOpen(BasicInfoWindow.java:86)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.infowindow.MarkerInfoWindow.onOpen(MarkerInfoWindow.java:55)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.JEB.trailmaps.MainActivity$CustomInfoWindow.onOpen(MainActivity.java:1329)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.infowindow.InfoWindow.open(InfoWindow.java:82)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker.showInfoWindow(Marker.java:281)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker.onMarkerClickDefault(Marker.java:438)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker.onSingleTapConfirmed(Marker.java:376)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onSingleTapConfirmed(DefaultOverlayManager.java:230)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.FolderOverlay.onSingleTapConfirmed(FolderOverlay.java:85)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onSingleTapConfirmed(DefaultOverlayManager.java:230)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at org.osmdroid.views.MapView$MapViewDoubleClickListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(MapView.java:1381)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:312)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
10-10 21:18:03.879 4519 4519 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Here's my code for the POIs

```
NominatimPOIProvider poiProvider = new NominatimPOIProvider("com.JEB.trailmaps/1.0");
        ArrayList<POI> pois = poiProvider.getPOIInside(map.getBoundingBox(),myString, 30);
        poiMarkers = new FolderOverlay(MainActivity.this);
        map.getOverlays().add(poiMarkers);
        if(myString.equals("Fuel")){
        poiIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gas);
        }if(myString.equals("Restaurant")){
            poiIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.food);
            }
        for (POI poi:pois){
            Marker poiMarker = new Marker(map);
            poiMarker.setTitle(poi.mType);
            poiMarker.setSnippet(poi.mDescription);
            poiMarker.setPosition(poi.mLocation);
            poiMarker.setIcon(poiIcon);

            if (poi.mThumbnail != null){
                poiMarker.setImage(new BitmapDrawable(poi.mThumbnail));
            }
            poiMarker.setInfoWindow(new CustomInfoWindow(map));
            poiMarker.setRelatedObject(poi);
            poiMarkers.add(poiMarker);
```

I have other markers and other overlays in my app as well and all those show my info window on click like it should.  I can't figure out what's going on that this won't work.  I've tried with and without the custom info window.  Either way I try, it crashes my app and gives me those errors.

I've also tried setting my info window like my other marker and that didn't work either.  This is how I set the custom info window for all my other markers and work on those.

```
InfoWindow infoWindow = new MyInfoWindow(R.layout.truck, MainActivity.this.map);
         startMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);
```